# Reference type in C#

Tags: c#, .net, pointers

Consider this code:

```
public class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var person1 = new Person { Name = "Test" };
        Console.WriteLine(person1.Name);

        Person person2 = person1;
        person2.Name = "Shahrooz";
        Console.WriteLine(person1.Name); //Output: Shahrooz
        person2 = null;
        Console.WriteLine(person1.Name); //Output: Shahrooz
    }
}

public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Obviously, when assigning `person1` to `person2` and the `Name` property of `person2` is changed, the `Name` of `person1` will also be changed. `person1` and `person2` have the same reference.

Why is it that when `person2 = null`, the `person1` variable will not be null either?

Answer (score 184, accepted):

Both `person` and `person2` are *references*, to the same object. But these are different references. So when you are running

```
person2 = null;
```

you are changing only reference `person2`, leaving reference `person` and the corresponding object unchanged.

I guess the best way to explain this is with a simplified illustration. Here is how the situation looked like *before* `person2 = null`:

[image: Before null assignment]

And here is the picture *after* the null assignment:

[image]

As you can see, on the second picture `person2` references nothing (or `null`, strictly speaking, since reference nothing and reference to `null` are different conditions, see comment by [Rune FS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/112407/rune-fs)), while `person` still references an existing object.

Comment: In other words, person and person2 points to something, then person2 points to nothing by setting to null.

Comment: @ShahroozJefriㇱ Basically, `person1` and `person2` are 2 different business cards that contain an address. If you do `person1 = person2` then `person1` is now a copy of `person2`. They are still *different* business cards, but they both contain the *same* address pointing towards the *same* object. The object itself does not change.

Comment: I'd remove the arrow on `person2` in the second picture because it references nothing - it's not a dangling reference.

Comment: @SameerSingh, done, thanks for response. I was thinking the same initially, but changed my mind for some reason.

Comment: When using references, creating a variable and assigning it to a another pointer, creates a thing callled Alias, where, we have let's say, 3 variables, pointing to the same memory location. When you nullify one of those variables, there's one variable less pointing to that memory location, when all the variables point to NULL, the GC cleans that location to allocate new variable, at least in Java the GC works that way D:

Comment: Actually person2 does reference something it reference null and is there for a null reference. null is different from nothing and null == null which can only be the case if null something (otherwise the operation would logically translate to just the operator which makes no sense) doesn't change the explanation (much) but person2 points to null

Answer (score 55):

Consider `person1` and `person2` **as pointers** to some location in storage. In the first step, only `person1` is holding the address of the object  from storage and later `person2` is holding the address of memory location of object  from storage. Later when you assign `null` to `person2`, `person1` stays unaffected. That is why you see the result.

You may read: [Value vs Reference Types from Joseph Albahari](http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx)

> With reference types, however, an object is created in memory, and
>   then handled through a separate reference—rather like a pointer.

I will try to depict the same concept using the following diagram.

[image]

Created a new object of type person and the `person1` reference (pointer) is pointing to the memory location in storage.

[image]

Created a new reference(pointer) `person2` which is pointing to the same in storage.

[image]

Changed the object property Name to new value, through `person2` since both references are pointing to the same object,`Console.WriteLine(person1.Name);` outputs `Shahrooz`.

[image]

After assigning `null` to `person2` reference, it will be pointing to nothing, but `person1` is still holding the reference to the object.

*(Finally for memory management you should see [The Stack Is An Implementation Detail, Part One](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail.aspx) and [The Stack Is An Implementation Detail, Part Two](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/04/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail-part-two.aspx) from Eric Lippert)*

Answer (score 14):

You have changed `person2` to reference `null`, but `person1` isn't referencing there.

What I mean is that if we look at `person2` and `person1` before the assignment then both reference the same object. Then you assign `person2 = null`, so person 2 is now referencing a different type. It did not delete the object that `person2` was referenced to.

I've created this gif to illustrate it:

[image]

Answer (score 13):

Because you've set the reference to `null`.

When you set a reference to `null`, the reference itself is `null`.. not the object it references.

Think of them as a variable that holds an offset from 0. `person` has the value 120. `person2` has the value 120. The data at offset 120 is the `Person` object. When you do this:

```
person2 = null;
```

..you're effectively saying, `person2 = 0;`. However, `person` still has the value 120.

Comment: so person 2 and person has not same reference?

Comment: They reference the same object.. but they are separate references. This comes down to `copy-by-value` semantics. You're copying the value of the reference.

Answer (score 4):

Both `person` and `person2` **point** to the same object. Therefore when you change the name of either one, both will get changed (since they point to the same structure in memory).

But when you set `person2` to `null`, you make `person2` into a null pointer, so that is does not **point** to the same object as `person` anymore. It wont do anything to the object itself to destroy it, and since `person` still points/references the object it wont get killed by garbage collection either.

If you also set `person = null`, and you have no other references to the object, it will eventually be removed by the garbage collector.

Answer (score 2):

`person1` and `person2` point to the same memory address. 
When you null `person2`, you null the reference, not the memory address, so `person1` continues reffering to that   memory address, that's the reason. If you change the `Classs Person` into a `Struct`, the behaviour will change.

Comment: They may or may not point to the same memory address (or any address, for that matter).  What is important is that they *identify the same object*.  On some kinds of concurrent garbage collector, it may be possible that while an object is being relocated some references may hold the old address while others identify the new one [code which writes to either address may have to block until all references were updated, and code which compares addresses would have to see if one address was "current" and the other wasn't and, if so, find the "new" address associated with the old one.]

Answer (score 2):

I find it most helpful to think of reference types as holding object IDs.  If one has a variable of class type `Car`, the statement `myCar = new Car();` asks the system to create a new car and report its ID (let's say it's object #57); it then puts "object #57" into variable `myCar`.  If one writes `Car2 = myCar;`, that writes "object #57" into variable Car2.  If one writes `car2.Color = blue;`, that instructs the system to find the car identified by Car2 (e.g. object #57) and paint it blue.

The only operations which are performed directly on object ID's are creation of a new object and getting the ID, getting a "blank" id (i.e. null), copying an object ID to a variable or storage location that can hold it, checking whether two object IDs match (refer to the same object).  All other requests ask the system to find the object referred to by an ID and act upon that object (without affecting the variable or other entity that held the ID).

In existing implementations of .NET, object variables are likely to hold pointers to objects stored on a garbage-collected heap, but that's an unhelpful implementation detail because there's a critical difference between an object reference and any other kind of pointer.  A pointer is generally assumed to represent the location of something which will stay put long enough to be worked with.  Object references don't.  A piece of code may load the SI register with a reference to an object located at address 0x12345678, start using it, and then be interrupted while the garbage collector moves the object to address 0x23456789.  That would sound like a disaster, but the garbage will examine the metadata associated with the code, observe that the code used SI to hold the address of the object it was using (i.e. 0x12345678), determine that object that was at 0x12345678 had been moved to 0x23456789, and update SI to hold 0x23456789 before it returned.  Note that in that scenario, the numerical value stored in SI was changed by the garbage collector, but it referred to *the same object* before the move and afterward.  If before the move it referred to the 23,592nd object created since program startup, it will continue to do so afterward.  Interestingly, .NET does not store any unique and immutable identifier for most objects; given two snapshots of a program's memory, it will not always be possible to tell whether any particular object in the first snapshot exists in the second, or if all traces to it have been abandoned and a new object created that happens to look like it in all observable details.

Answer (score 1):

person1 and person2 are two separate references on the stack that point to the same Person object on the heap.

When you delete one of the references, it is removed from the stack and no longer points to the Person object on the heap. The other reference remains, still pointing to the existing Person object on the heap.

Once all references to the Person object are removed, then eventually the Garbage Collector will removed the object from memory.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a reference type its actually copying a reference with all objects pointing to the same memory location , However If you have assigned Person2=Null  it will have no effect as person2 is just a copy of reference person and we have just **erased a copy of reference** .

Answer (score 1):

Note that you can get value semantics by changing to a `struct`.

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var person1 = new Person { Name = "Test" };
        Console.WriteLine(person1.Name);

        Person person2 = person1;
        person2.Name = "Shahrooz";
        Console.WriteLine(person1.Name);//Output:Test
        Console.WriteLine(person2.Name);//Output:Shahrooz
        person2 = new Person{Name = "Test2"};
        Console.WriteLine(person2.Name);//Output:Test2

    }
}
public struct Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var person = new Person {Name = "Test"};
        Console.WriteLine(person.Name);

        Person person2 = person;
        person2.Name = "Shahrooz";
        Console.WriteLine(person.Name);//Output:Shahrooz
        // Here you are just erasing a copy to reference not the object created.
        // Single memory allocation in case of reference type and  parameter
         // are passed as a copy of reference type .   
        person2 = null;
        Console.WriteLine(person.Name);//Output:Shahrooz

    }
}
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: @doctorlove forgot the comments actually:-( , Well For reference type only one memory space is allocated and Person 2 or Person 1... are just copy of that reference type which are pointing toward the memory location , Erasing a copy of reference type will not affect anything .

Answer (score 0):

You first copy the reference to `person1` to `person2`. Now `person1` and `person2` refer to the same object, which means modifications to the value of that object (i.e changing the `Name` property) can be observed under both variables. Then, when assigning null, you are removing the reference you just assigned to `person2`. It is only assigned to `person1` now. Note that the reference itself is **not** changed.

If you had a function that accepted an argument by reference, you could pass `reference to person1` **by reference**, and would be able to change the reference itself:

```
public class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var person1 = new Person { Name = "Test" };
        Console.WriteLine(person1.Name);

        PersonNullifier.NullifyPerson(ref person1);
        Console.WriteLine(person1); //Output: null
    }
}


class PersonNullifier
{
    public static void NullifyPerson( ref Person p ) {
        p = null;
    }
}

class  Person {
    public string Name{get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Saying:

```
person2.Name = "Shahrooz";
```

follows the reference of `person2` and "mutates" (changes) the object that the reference happens to lead to. The reference itself (the *value* of `person2`) is unchanged; we still refer the same instance at the same "address".

Assigning to `person2` as in:

```
person2 = null;
```

changes the *reference*. No object gets changed. In this case the reference arrow is "moved" from one object to "nothing", `null`. But an assignment like `person2 = new Person();` would also only change the reference. No object is mutated.