# Why is this not throwing a NullPointerException?

Tags: java, reference, nullpointerexception

Nead clarification for following code:

```
StringBuilder sample = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder referToSample = sample;
referToSample.append("B");
System.out.println(sample);
```

This will print `B` so that proves `sample` and `referToSample` objects refer to the same memory reference.

```
StringBuilder sample = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder referToSample = sample;
sample.append("A");
referToSample.append("B");
System.out.println(referToSample);
```

This will print `AB` that also proves the same.

```
StringBuilder sample = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder referToSample = sample;
referToSample = null;
referToSample.append("A");
System.out.println(sample);
```

Obviously this will throw `NullPointerException` because I am trying to call `append` on a null reference.

```
StringBuilder sample = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder referToSample = sample;
referToSample = null;
sample.append("A");
System.out.println(sample);
```

So Here is my question, why is  the last code sample not throwing `NullPointerException` because what I see and understand from first two examples is if two objects referring to same object then if we change any value then it will also reflect to other because both are pointing to same memory reference. So why is that rule not applying here? If I assign `null` to referToSample then sample should also be null and it should throw a NullPointerException but it is not throwing one, why?

Comment: `sample` is still `sample`. You only changed `referToSample`.

Comment: Upvoted/starred! Very basic question, but this is a beautiful example of explaining your problem *and* asking the question well.

Comment: @DaveNewton I am asking the same, this rule should also apply for first two example.

Comment: What rule do you refer to?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels now I got clear

Comment: One point of terminology in your question: you keep referring to `sample` and `referToSample` as **objects** but they aren't objects, they are variables. A variable can hold a reference to an object, but it is not itself an object. It's a subtle distinction, but it's basically the essence of your confusion.

Comment: Wait I think I saw a similar question just a few weeks ago... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18229463/reference-type-in-c-sharp

Comment: It helps to think of object variables as just pointers. Any operator which acts on a variable (`volatile`, `final`, `=`, `==`...) when applied to an object variable affects the _pointer_, not the object it refers to.

Comment: @AlvinWong I am not aware of C# and haven't look for the same ever.

Comment: This is a perfect example of asking a simple question in stupendous manner. When i was reading through it, i thought something big concept is hidden inside but the last example was like :D .

Comment: @Arpit I respectfully disagree. There is a big concept hidden in this question, and that is, the difference between an _object_ and a _reference_ to that object. Most of the time, we don't need (nor want) to be aware of this difference, and language designers work hard to hide it from us. Just think of pass-by-reference arguments in C++, for instance. So it's not surprising to me to see  beginners confused by all that magic !

Comment: @Gyom if you prefer a good book then its not difficult to understand this concept. :)

Comment: @Arpit There *is* a lesson and a concept here. You may be experienced with Java and consider it trivial, but for somebody entering Java as a first language or especially from something like pure C(or even assembly), this concept may be new and counterintuitive.

Comment: @hexafraction I'm not saying anything about why it is asked. But the question is simple, Now again the thing is which book one is referring. If one is writing that program it means that one is familiar with the object and classes. isn't it? and if one is familiar with objects then i can safely assume that if the book were good then this doubt wouldn't be present.

Comment: @Arpit The book will likely leave it out as it's not of great importance for someone that is picking up Java *as a first language*. For someone migrating, they *already* have concepts in their mind, and probably use idioms that would break upon the pass-by-value-of-reference way of passing objects in Java.

Comment: @hexafraction in that case i will say "Choose your book wisely". and if the book is skipping this concept then one should change it immediately.

Comment: @Arpit sometimes we get better idea about the thing by asking the peoples who know about it rather going to find it in books, that's why we all are here.

Comment: @commit Now this is something that matches to me. :)

Answer (score 90, accepted):

`null` assignments do not change *value* by globally destroying that object. That kind of behavior would lead to hard-to-track bugs and counterintuitive behavior. They only break that specific *reference*.

For simplicity, let's say that `sample` points to address 12345. This is probably not the address, and is only used to make things simple here. <strike>The address is *typically* represented with the weird hexadecimal given in `Object#hashCode()`, but this is implementation-dependent.</strike><sup>1</sup>

```
StringBuilder sample = new StringBuilder(); //sample refers to 
//StringBuilder at 12345 

StringBuilder referToSample = sample; //referToSample refers to 
//the same StringBuilder at 12345 
//SEE DIAGRAM 1

referToSample = null; //referToSample NOW refers to 00000, 
//so accessing it will throw a NPE. 
//The other reference is not affected.
//SEE DIAGRAM 2

sample.append("A"); //sample STILL refers to the same StringBuilder at 12345 
System.out.println(sample);
```

*From the lines marked `See diagram` the diagrams of the objects at that time are as follows:*

**Diagram 1:**

```
[StringBuilder sample]    -----------------> [java.lang.StringBuilder@00012345]
                                                      ↑
[StringBuilder referToSample] ------------------------/
```

**Diagram 2:**

```
[StringBuilder sample]    -----------------> [java.lang.StringBuilder@00012345]

[StringBuilder referToSample] ---->> [null pointer]
```

Diagram 2 shows that annulling `referToSample` does not break the reference of `sample` to the StringBuilder at `00012345`.

<sub><sup>1</sup>GC considerations make this implausible.</sub>

Comment: @commit, if this answers your question, please click the tick below the vote arrows to the left of the text above.

Comment: @RayBritton I love how people assume that the highest voted answer is the one that necesarily answers the question. While that count is important it is not the only metric; -1 and -2 answers can get accepted just because they helped the OP the most.

Comment: @hexafraction I thought `null` is a value so if I assign to one it should also assign to other but as simple example given by you I got clear and just for I want to know that if I assign any object with `null` it will refer to `00000` kind of address or is just an example?

Comment: @commit Yes, it will refer to a special address(or one of a set) that means a null value, presumably 000000. The numbers here are examples, however. It just means that it's just referring to nothing in particular.

Comment: @hexafraction I asked commit to mark your answer correct as they said that your answer had answered their question.

Comment: `hashCode()` is **not** the same thing as memory address

Comment: @KevinPanko Right, Object#hashCode is native and implementation-dependent. Better now?

Comment: The identity hashCode is typically derived from the Object’s memory location the first time the method is called. From then on that hashCode is fixed and remembered even if the memory manager decides to move the object to a different memory location.

Comment: Classes which override `hashCode` typically define it to return a value that has nothing to do with memory addresses.  I think you can make your point about object references vs. objects without mentioning  `hashCode`.  The finer points of how to get the memory address can be left for another day.

Comment: @KevinPanko I am not referring to overridden hash codes, namely `Object#hashCode`. Removed, anyway,

Comment: for 2 given objects of the same class; a and b | hashCode(a) == hashCode(b) ~ a.equals(b) but not necessarily a == b

Comment: @KhaledAKhunaifer Yes, that is correct. I was discussing the special implementation of `identityHashCode` which was used in `Object#hashCode` when no hashcode was specifically provided, but this is really not the place to jump into said intricacies as Kevin Panko mentioned.

Answer (score 62):

Initially it was as you said `referToSample` was referring to `sample` as shown below:

***1. Scenario1:***

[image: referToSample refers to sample]

***2. Scenario1 (cont.):***

[image: referToSample.append("B")]

- Here as `referToSample` was referring to `sample`, so it appended "B"
  while you write

  `referToSample.append("B")`

Same thing happend in ***Scenario2 :***

But, in  ***3. Scenario3 :*** as hexafraction said,

when you assign `null` to `referToSample` when it was referring `sample` it did not change **value** instead it just breaks the **reference** from `sample`, and now it points *nowhere*. as shown below:

[image: when referToSample = null]

Now, as `referToSample` points *nowhere*, so while you `referToSample.append("A");` it would not be have any values or reference where it can append A. So, it would throw `NullPointerException`.

BUT `sample` is still the same as you had initialized it with

`StringBuilder sample = new StringBuilder();` so it has been initalized, so now it can append A, and will not throw `NullPointerException`

Comment: Nice diagrams. Helps to illustrate it.

Comment: nice diagram, but the note at the bottom should be 'Now referToSample does not refer to ""' because when you do `referToSample = sample;` you are referring to sample, you're just copying the address of what is referenced

Answer (score 17):

In a nutshell: You assign null to a reference variable, not to an object.

In one example you change the *state* of an object that is referred to by two reference variables. When this occurs, both reference variables will reflect the change.

In another example, you change the reference assigned to one variable, but this has no effect on the object itself, and so the second variable, which still refers to the original object, will not notice any change in object state.

---

So as to your specific "rules":

> if two objects referring to same object then if we change any value then it will also reflect to other because both are pointing to same memory reference.

Again, you refer to changing the *state* of the one object that both *variables* refer to.

> So why is that rule not applying here? If I assign null to referToSample then sample should also be null and it should throw nullPointerException but it is not throwing, why?

Again, you change the *reference* of one variable which has absolutely *no effect* on the *reference* of the other variable.

These are two completely different actions and will result in two completely different results.

Comment: @commit: it's a basic but critical concept that underlies all of Java and that once you see, you'll never forget.

Answer (score 8):

See this simple diagram:

[image: diagram]

When you call a **method** on `referToSample`, then `[your object]` is updated, so it affects `sample` too. But when you say `referToSample = null`, then you're simply changing what `referToSample` **refers** to.

Answer (score 3):

Here 'sample' and 'referToSample' are referencing the same object.That is the concept of different pointer accessing same memory location. So assigning one reference variable to null does not destroy the object.

```
   referToSample = null;
```

means 'referToSample' only pointing to null , object remains same and other reference variable are working fine. So for 'sample' which does not pointing to null and have a valid object

```
   sample.append("A");
```

works fine. But if we try to append null to 'referToSample', it will show NullPointException.
That is,

```
   referToSample .append("A");-------> NullPointerException
```

That is why you got NullPointerException in your third code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever a **new** keyword is used it Creates a Object at the Heap

1)StringBuilder sample = new StringBuilder();

2)**StringBuilder referToSample = sample;**

In 2) the Reference of referSample is created on same object sample

thus **referToSample = null;** 
is Nulling Only the referSample Reference giving no effect to sample
that's why you are not getting NULL Pointer Exception 
Thanks to Java's Garbage Collection

Answer (score 0):

Just easy, Java don't have pass by reference, It just pass object reference.

Comment: Parameter-passing semantics don't really have anything to do with the situation as described.