# Java copy multi-d array, random errors

Tags: java, arrays

I have been debugging my implementation of Game of Life, and my main problem looks like its coming from how I use arrays.

```
public boolean[][] oldState;
public boolean[][] newState;
private boolean gameState = true;

public LifeBoard(Seed seed) {
    oldState = seed.getSeed();
    newState = new boolean[oldState.length][oldState[0].length];
    run();
}

public void run() {
    //debug code to run for x generations
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        BoardPrinter.print(oldState);
        evaluateCells();
        oldState = newState;        
    }
    BoardPrinter.print(oldState);
    System.out.println("game over");
}
```

the boolean[][] from Seed is a 5x5 grid, all false (dead) except the 3 horizontal middle cells in the middle row

```
00000
00000
0+++0
00000
00000
```

evaluateCells() looks at each cell in the grid, looks at the 8 cells around it, counts them, and based on the number of neighbors it writes a new value to newState.

What should happen: use oldState to calculate newState, copy newState to oldState, then go back through newState, writing each cell again based on the new oldState.

What really happens:  the first generation works correctly, but after that the results are increasingly weird, it evaluates cells to be false that I know to be true, etc.  The problem seems to be in the way I am copying the arrays.

If I initialize a 3rd blank array blankState[][] = new boolean[5][5];
and during the loop in run say:

```
public void run() {
    //debug code to run for x generations
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        BoardPrinter.print(oldState);
        evaluateCells();
        oldState = newState;
            newState = blankState;
    }
    BoardPrinter.print(oldState);
    System.out.println("game over");
}
```

...then the game works correctly for an additional 1 generation, then the weird garbage returns.

I have 2 questions: first, it looks like I have to use System.arraycopy(), but unless someone tells me about a version for multidimensional arrays, I will have to write a simple loop.

My real question: why do you have to use this special System method to copy an array?  Why can't you use the = operator?

EDIT: the conceptual answer is accepted below.  Here is the code that solved the implementation problem:

```
for (int n = 0; n < oldState.length; n++) {
            System.arraycopy(newState[n], 0, oldState[n], 0, oldState.length);
}
for (int t = 0; t < newState.length; t++) {
            System.arraycopy(blankState[t], 0, newState[t], 0, newState.length);
}
```

Also for the record, `System.arraycopy(boolean[][], 0, boolean[][], 0, boolean.length);` did not work correctly, you have to iterate through each line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> My real question: why do you have to use this special System method to copy an array? Why can't you use the = operator?

This is actually an important Java lesson, so ***pay attention***. Are you paying attention? Good. This will be important in the future.

Now, this applies for all objects in Java, as arrays are objects. If you use `=` then you only set the reference, and encounter all kinds of fun as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18636561/why-is-this-not-throwing-a-nullpointerexception/18636608#18636608). Namely, if I have a simple class with a getter and setter called `TestClass` with a public int `test`, then the following code will work:

```
TestClass t=new TestClass();
t.test=1;
TestClass t1=t;
t1.test=6;
System.out.println(t.test); //prints 6.
```

Now, why? Because the references `t` and `t1` point to the **same** object on the heap. And *this holds for arrays as well*. To get copies, you need to perform tasks that are object-specific. Some let you call `clone()` directly(`Cloneable` interface), some let you pass another instance into the constructor to get a new instance(Like the ArrayList constructor), and some use utility methods, like arrays here.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, I hadn't realized/remembered arrays were objects, I was thinking that arrays of primitive types were also primitive types.

Comment: @nexus_2006 No, primitive arrays could have caused a big hit for performance when being passed around. They live on the heap, and live and die with other objects.

Comment: Oh, I see.  arrays can be huge, and primitives would be duplicated whereas objects can simply move.

Answer (score 1):

> evaluateCells() looks at each cell in the grid, looks at the 8 cells
>   around it, counts them, and based on the number of neighbors it writes
>   a new value to newState.
>
> What should happen: use oldState to calculate newState, copy newState
>   to oldState, then go back through newState, writing each cell again
>   based on the new oldState.
>
> What really happens: the first generation works correctly, but after
>   that the results are increasingly weird, it evaluates cells to be
>   false that I know to be true, etc. The problem seems to be in the way
>   I am copying the arrays.

Without seeing your bit shifting code, I'd bet this is caused by a higher level problem. Most likely your bit shifting algorithm has a bug somewhere.

Have you stepped through your code with Eclipse's debugger? If not, read this tutorial and try a few different seeds. This will tell you where, if anywhere, in your algorithm the bit shift error occurs.

http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseDebugging/article.html

Comment: Thanks for the input, but I'm very sure the model works, after I started copying the 2d arrays correctly, the code works great with no further refinements - all seeds I give it work as expected, oscillators, pulsars, spaceships, puffer trains, etc.  I wrote this entire app with command line tools and gedit, but I do use Eclipse for Android dev, thanks for the link.