# Why is this throwing null pointer exception?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I have already asked one of the contradiction question here 
[Why is this not throwing a NullPointerException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18636561/why-is-this-not-throwing-a-nullpointerexception)

But this is one of different type and behavior I want to know about, please look for my example below

```
package com;

public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Abc abc = null;

        //Scenario 1
        System.out.println("ERROR HERE " + abc!=null?abc.getS1():""); //This is throwing null pointer exception 

        //Scenario 2
        String s1 = abc!=null?abc.getS1():"";
        System.out.println("This is fine " + s1);
    }
}

class Abc {
    String s1;

    public String getS1() {
        return s1;
    }

    public void setS1(String s1) {
        this.s1 = s1;
    }


}
```

So here **Scenario 2** will work fine but why it is not working when I am trying it with other string concatenation in **Scenario 1**?

Comment: Due to order of evaluation of argument to `println()` in 1st case, `"ERROR HERE " + abc` is evaluated first and gives NPE.

Answer (score 5):

```
"ERROR HERE " + abc!=null?abc.getS1():""
```

is equivalent to

```
("ERROR HERE " + abc!=null)?abc.getS1():""
```

(which never evaluates to false and therefore you get NPE)

You meant:

```
"ERROR HERE " + (abc!=null?abc.getS1():"")
```

Comment: Operator precedence rules are here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

Comment: The '+' operator is higher on the list than the ternary conditional operator '?:'.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to separate it (with brackets) so that it's read as a whole separate statement

```
System.out.println("ERROR HERE " + (abc != null ? abc.getS1() : ""));
```

Answer (score 0):

+1 vote for Eyal and Ross.

After seeing both that answer and comment by Tenner, I have concluded that,

it is throwing `nullPointerException` because **!=** operator priority is lower than **+**.

So compiler is calling `toString` method of **Abc** class and hence **abc** is **null** it is throwing `nullPointerException`.

Please correct me if I am wrong.