# how come `"a1" == "a1";` returns true?

Tags: java, reference, equals

I know `==` compares references.

And `equals` compares content.

How come  `"a1" == "a1";` returns true?

It's a different instance if string after all. no?

Comment: The accepted answer covers this case.

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18636561/why-is-this-not-throwing-a-nullpointerexception/18644819#18644819

Comment: duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052442/what-is-the-difference-between-text-and-new-stringtext-in-java

Comment: In case its not clear, Java interns String literals so in your code the two String literals are actually the same object. If you were to change it to 'new String("a1") = "a1";' then it would be false.