# C# objects and memory managment

Tags: c#, object

Lets say i have the following code where Car class has only 1 property : `String modelname`

```
Car c = new Car("toyota");
Car c1 = c;
Car c2 = c;
Car c3 = c;
Car c4 = c;
Car c5 = c;
```

Is this going to make a new copy of car c every time ? So there will be a new "toyota" String 5 times more in the memory ? Or the "toyota" string will be in the memory only once ?

Edit: Adding this relevant link in case you had the same question as i did, i think it helps  [Are arrays or lists passed by default by reference in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/967402/are-arrays-or-lists-passed-by-default-by-reference-in-c)

Comment: You are just creating references, and all of them would be pointing to a single object.

Comment: This is such a fundamental aspect of the language that you should research it in detail. The answers here will not provide you with the required level of understanding.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18229463/reference-type-in-c-sharp

Comment: Also, C# strings are immutable and each unique  string is in memory only once, even if you make a **deep** copy of your car

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the "toyota" string will be in memory only once, because there will only be one Car object, with 6 references pointing to it.

Comment: Then how come when i do c = new car("something"); then the c1,c2,c3,c4,c5 doesnt change modelname ?

Comment: Because `c` is a variable of reference type.  You're making a second `Car` and assigning it to `c`, while `c1`-`c5` still point to the original `Car`.

Comment: @Shiro Because you mutated the value of the variable, you didn't mutate the object that all 5 references pointed to.

Comment: so there will be two cars both named c ? the "old" and the "new" one ?

Comment: No.  There will be two `Cars`, the first one referenced by `c1`, `c2`, `c3`, `c4`, and `c5`, and the second one referenced by `c` ("named `c`" if that's how you want to think of it).  Each variable points to exactly one instance of `Car`, but one of the `Cars` is referenced by more than one variable.

Comment: Now i completely understand it yea. I am actually not new at all in programming, especially with C#, but that part wasn't clear in my head. Do you know if java works with the same way as well ?

Comment: @Shiro, yes, Java and C# behave similarly in this respect.

Comment: @Shiro You say you are not new to programming, are you coming from C++ by any chance? If you are think of the `.` in C# to behave like `->` on a pointer in C++ (This only applies to classes, different rules apply to structs). So if you had 6 pointers and you assigned a new value to the first pointer, of course 2-6 would not have their value changed.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I thought that in the line `Car c = new Car(13000, "toyota");` , the `Car c` and the `new Car(13000, "toyota")`  is  exactly the same thing. So when i later changed the `c` value i thought that `c1 - c5` would change as well. I got that wrong. But i quickly understood how it actually works when adv12 explained it to me

Comment: What would I have to change to the line `Car c1 = c;` to make it so that whenever c values were changed , c1 values would change as well ?

Comment: @Shiro, you need to understand the difference between modifying the properties of an object and creating a new one.  After the initialization shown in your question, you could say `c.modelname = "foo"`, which *modifies a property of the object pointed to by c*, and all other variables pointing to that object (`c1` - `c5`) would reflect the change (i.e. `c1.modelname` would also be "foo").  But if you make a new `Car` and assign it to `c`, then `c` and `c1` would point to completely different objects, and modifying one would have no effect on the other.

Comment: oh wow, again thanks for the quick response :) I understood your answer :)

Answer (score 3):

Car is a [Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/490f96s2(v=vs.110).aspx) type, so the answer is no. See: [What is the difference between a reference type and value type in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057267/what-is-the-difference-between-a-reference-type-and-value-type-in-c).

Answer (score 2):

Assigning a reference type is only copies the *reference* (in other words address) of the `object` into the variable. It doesn't copy the actual `data` since the reference type variables only hold reference values or in other words an address that indicates where the actual data lives in memory. So in this case you will have 6 reference type variable that hold a reference to the same address in the memory.

Comment: `copies the reference (in other words address)` Reference isn't address.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan yes it is. names can be different but they are same thing.a reference hold an address just like a pointer. otherwise how could it allow you to access actual object, if it doesn't hold an address? here is a relevant question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/430112/what-is-the-difference-between-a-c-sharp-reference-and-a-pointer

Comment: No, it isn't it. Reference - just a reference, no more, anything beyond this comes from the evil (i.e. implementation detail) :)