# Initialize multiple List<Boolean> vs multiple List<String>

Tags: c#, .net, list

I used to have in my code the following class

```
public class SomeListClass
{ 
       public List<Boolean> ListA {get; set;}
       public List<Boolean> ListB {get; set;}

       public List<String> ListStringsA {get; set;}
       public List<String> ListStringsB {get; set;}
       public List<String> ListStringsC {get; set;}
       public List<String> ListStringsD {get; set;}

       public void InitLists()
       {
            ListStringsA  = ListStringsB = ListStringsC = ListStringsD = new List<String>();
            ListA = ListB = new List<Boolean>();
       }
}
```

What did I notice using this initialisation and the following piece of code:

```
SomeListClass itm = new SomeListClass();
itm.InitLists();
itm.ListStringsA.Add("TestString");
itm.ListA.Add(true);
```

- If I add a String to `ListStringsA`, then it gets only added to `ListStringsA`
- If I add a Boolean to `ListA` then it get automatically added to `ListB`

So the result would be:

```
ListStringsA = {"TestString"}
ListStringsB = {}
ListStringsC = {}
ListStringsD = {}
ListA  = {true}
ListB = {true}
```

What is the reason herefor? Could someone point me some to some documentation explaining this odd behavior? I can't seem to find anything.

**Note: This solved it:**

```
   public void InitLists()
   {
        ListStringsA = ListStringsB = ListStringsC = ListStringsD = new List<String>();
        ListA = new List<Boolean>();
        ListB = new List<Boolean>();
   }
```

**Note: Some simplyfied production code:**

I get a list of type `SomeListObject` (see Below) named `objectList`

```
public class SomeListObject {
    public String SomeListObjectName {get; set;}
    public Boolean SomeListObjectNeeded {get; set;}
    public Boolean SomeListObjectOk {get; set;}
}
```

The list contains 2 items:

```
objectList = {{SomeListObjectName  = "PersonA", SomeListObjectNeeded  = true, SomeListObjectOk = false},{SomeListObjectName  = "PersonB", SomeListObjectNeeded  = true, SomeListObjectOk = false}}
```

Then I do a foreach:

```
SomeListClass itm = new SomeListClass();
itm.InitLists();
foreach (SomeListObject  myObj in objectList )
{
      ListStringsA.Add(myObj.SomeListObjectName);
      // ListStringsA: {"PersonA"}
      // ListStringsB: {}
      // ListA: {}
      // ListB: {}
      ListA.Add(myObj.SomeListObjectNeeded);
      // ListStringsA: {"PersonA"}
      // ListStringsB: {}
      // ListA: {true}
      // ListB: {true}
      ListB.Add(myObj.SomeListObjectNeeded);
      // ListStringsA: {"PersonA"}
      // ListStringsB: {}
      // ListA: {true, false}
      // ListB: {true, false} <=== Say What now???

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Can you post a complete compilable console app that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @MatthewWatson I'll try to create and squeeze one in the question.

Answer (score 5):

This happens because you're creating only one list for `bool` and `string`, then just assigning it to variable. [See more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18229463/reference-type-in-c-sharp).

If you want to create new list for each property, see this:

`ListStringsA = new List<string>();
 ListStringsB = new List<string>();
 ListStringsC = new List<string>();
 ListA = new List<bool>();
 ListB = new List<bool>();`

Comment: Unfortunatly this is not the case. I would expect the same behavior your're displaying. Except it doesn't.

Comment: @User999999: Are you saying that if you put the code you've given in post to your new project (without any additions), it doesn't give you the expected output? Don't forget that there is no point to talk about this problem if you're actually comparing some other code, instead the **EXACT** one you have in the post.

Comment: I have supplied some extra code in the question. It is as a matter of fact the productioncode only the names of the properties have been changed.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure?? I suppose that the result should be

```
ListStringsA = {"TestString"}
ListStringsB = {"TestString"}
ListStringsC = {"TestString"}
ListStringsD = {"TestString"}
ListA  = {true}
ListB = {true}
```

Comment: Yes I'm sure. Im stumped by the behavior. I would expect the same result you're posting.

Comment: That's quite strange if you have that result.

Comment: Posted some simplified productioncode above (less objects in class, same logic).

Answer (score 1):

Try for youreself

```
SomeList mysomelist = new SomeList();

mysomelist.InitLists();

mysomelist.ListA.Add(true);
mysomelist.ListStringsA.Add("a");

Console.WriteLine(mysomelist.ListA[0] + "   " + mysomelist.ListB[0]);
Console.WriteLine(mysomelist.ListStringsA[0] + "   " + mysomelist.ListStringsB[0] + "  " + mysomelist.ListStringsC[0] + "  " + mysomelist.ListStringsD[0]);
```

Output :

```
True    True 
a    a    a    a
```

Edit : may be you are trying something other than what's stated in the question

Comment: I did, otherwise I wouldn't ask it here.  I will post a simplied version of the production code above.

Comment: Did you check the given example :)