# When I change the value of a variable which is a copy of another, it changes the original variable also

Tags: c#, class, variables

```
public class TestClass
{
    public int TestNumber;
    public string TestName;

    public TestClass(string name, int number)
    {
        TestName   = name;
        TestNumber = number;
    }
}

public class AnotherClass
{  
    TestClass Var1, Var2;

    void Start()
    {
         Var1 = new TestClass("Me", 1);
         Var2 = Var1;
         Var2.TestName = "aaa";
    }
}
```

When I debug the value of `Var1.TestName` I get `"aaa"` but originally it was `"Me"`. How can I separate each var but still `Var2` gets its initial values from `Var1`?

Comment: Not sure if it's an exact duplicate, but you might find some good information here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18229463/reference-type-in-c-sharp In fact, a Google search for "Stack Overflow c# reference type" finds several questions which relate to this concept, and you'll probably learn from all of them.

Comment: [What is the difference between a variable, object and reference?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32010172/what-is-the-difference-between-a-variable-object-and-reference/32010236#32010236) and also [C# Concepts Value vs Reference Types](http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx)

Comment: You shouldn't expose your fields to user. They should be `private` or `protected`, but almost never public.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is your problem:

```
Var1=new TestClass("Me",1);
Var2 = Var1;
Var2.TestName="aaa";
```

`Var2 = Var1;` is actually a reference copy! This means that the `Var2` will take the address of `Var1` and no matter what you modify in either of them, it will be visible in the other. To get that, I would recommend using a copy of `Var2`. To do so, create a method in your `testClass` class.

```
public testClass copy()
{
    testClass tC = new testClass(this.TestNumber, this.TestName);
    return tC;
}
```

Now you can assign the value like this: `Var2 = Var1.copy();`

Comment: Thank you, that what i was looking for.

Comment: @Forenkazan, then why didn't you mark my answer as the right answer?

Comment: i did, marked you and the other guy as correct answers.

Comment: In SO (stackOverflow) you can only mark a single answer, unfortunately. Please, for future, **don't** expose your field members like that. A user should not be allowed to modify the inner values of a field.

Answer (score 0):

C# is a [pass by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value) language, when dealing with objects. So when you say `Var2 = Var`, you're saying that `Var2` now holds the address of whatever address `Var1` was holding, effectively making them point to the same object.

One work around is to turn it into a pass by value, like so:

```
public void Start()
{
    Var1 = new TestClass("Me", 1);
    Var2 = new TestClass();           // You would need a default constructor, and to use it to prevent the null exception error

    Var2.TestNumber = Var1.TestNumber;
    Var2.TestName   = "aaa";

}
```

Or, if you will be using more values and this is an overly simplified example, you can use another approach:

```
public void Start()
{
    Var1 = new TestClass("Me", 1);
    Var2 = Var1.GetValues();
}
```

And in your test class:

```
public testClass GetValues() => return new testClass(TestNumber, TestName);
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped :) but what is that "=>" ?

Comment: No problem :) And that is a little shorthand for writing methods in one line of code, I think its very clean :) They're called expression bodied functions. You can find out more about them, and all the other C# 6 features, here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802602.aspx :)