# Strange Image variable behavior

Tags: c#, image, winforms

I have two `PictureBoxes` where I want to show an image in the first and then a rotated version in the second. The code I would believe should work does act strange however, as the image is rotated in both `PictureBoxes`:

```
Image im = Image.FromFile(D:\somefolder\picture.jpg");            
pictureBox1.Image = im;
Image im_rot = im;
//Image im_rot = Image.FromFile(D:\somefolder\picture.jpg");
im_rot.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipNone);
pictureBox2.Image = im_rot;
```

If I replace line 3 with line 4 it works, but why doesn't it work the other way?

Comment: You should read about reference types vs value types.

Comment: Hm, OK, thought they were independent variables. Will look into this. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When I change the value of a variable which is a copy of another, it changes the original variable also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35395500/when-i-change-the-value-of-a-variable-which-is-a-copy-of-another-it-changes-the)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way your code is currently written, you're assigning the same object to both variables. This means that when you operate on either one, it's changing the same object in memory. With the alternate code you have commented out, you create a new, distinct object which is assigned to each variable.