# Does assigning new values to variables originally set from objects back propagate and effect the object?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am creating a game that must calculate differences in player stats (Blood Bowl for those curious) and have written a routine to do such. However I am worried that changing variables may change the objects, which I do not want.

```
MyPanel AttackerCell = Frm_Menu.GameBoard.SelectedCell;
MyPanel DefenderCell = this;

int AttackerStrength = AttackerCell.PlayerOnCell.ST;
int DefenderStrength = PlayerOnCell.ST;

if (DefenderStrength > AttackerStrength && AttackerCell.PlayerOnCell.Skills.Contains("Dauntless"))
{
    Random Dice = new Random();
    int DiceResult = Dice.Next(1, 7);

    if (DiceResult + AttackerStrength < DefenderStrength)
    {
        AttackerStrength = DefenderStrength;
    }
}
```

PlayerOnCell is of custom type player - and has an integer property called ST (Strength)

ignoring the if statements, they are to do with the game rules, the line AttackerStrength = DefenderStength; possess my issue.

Will the new assignment of AttackerStrength propagate back and effect AttackerCell.PlayerOnCell.ST? If so, how do I stop this?

Comment: *"Will the new assignment of AttackerStrength propagate back and effect AttackerCell.PlayerOnCell.ST?"* Try it?

Comment: It could be an issue if dealing with reference types (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35395500/when-i-change-the-value-of-a-variable-which-is-a-copy-of-another-it-changes-the). But `int` is a value type - so nothing to worry about - the values are completely independent.

Answer (score 2):

No, because in this scenario `AttackerStrength` is declared as a local variable; assigning to `AttackerStrength` *only* changes the local variable. However! This is actually a nuanced topic:

If the local variable is an *object*, then changes to the *state of the object* are propagated, as there is *only one object*; i.e.

```
SomeObject foo = PlayerOnCell.Foo;
// ...
foo.Strength = 42; // will be seen everywhere; only one object
```

But if the local variable is a *struct*, then this **does not happen**, as assigning to `foo` **copies** the value:

```
SomeStruct foo = PlayerOnCell.Foo;
// ...
foo.Strength = 42; // not propagated - foo is a copy
```

(this confusion, btw, is a good reason to avoid mutable structs - they are evil! structs are rare, and in that rare event when you create one, you should default to `readonly struct`).

Likewise, if you are using "ref returns" and "ref locals", then you can end up changing the remote state - but you can't do this accidentally, as it requires specific `ref` syntax *and* an up-to-date compiler:

```
ref int DefenderStrength = ref PlayerOnCell.ST;
// ...
DefenderStrength = 42; // this will have changed the state inside PlayerOnCell
```

This also applies to the `SomeStruct` scenario if using "ref returns" and "ref locals":

```
ref SomeStruct foo = ref PlayerOnCell.Foo;
// ...
foo.Strength = 42; // updates the value from PlayerOnCell
```

(at this point we're mixing multiple very advanced concepts, so it is *very* rare you'd need to know about this last scenario in real code; and if you *are* in that world, almost all confusion here can be avoided by saying that all `struct` should either be `readonly struct` (the default) or `ref struct` (if it absolutely must be mutable) - that guidance stops you triggering almost all traps)

Answer (score 0):

It will not propagate back because it was assigned by value, not by reference.